# unable to run my rails application with mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

I am working on rails project where i have used **mongodb** as backend , i am using **mongo_mapper** as ORM , i have followed the instructions from the below site 
  : http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+3+-+Getting+Started .
But while running the server (i.e rails s or rails c) i am getting the following error.

```
/home/vijay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:196:in `merge!': can't convert String into Hash (TypeError)
    from /home/vijay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:196:in `block in visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
    from /home/vijay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:190:in `each'
    from /home/vijay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:190:in `each_slice'
    from /home/vijay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:190:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
    from /home/vijay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:7:in `accept'
    from /home/vijay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:16:in `accept'
    from /home/vijay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/node.rb:25:in `to_ruby'
    from /home/vijay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:107:in `load'
    from /home/vijay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mongo_mapper-0.11.0/lib/mongo_mapper/railtie.rb:27:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/vijay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/vijay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/vijay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/vijay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /home/vijay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/vijay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
    from /home/vijay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/vijay/Desktop/rails_project/newfolder/Mongo_St/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vijay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in `require'
    from /home/vijay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in `require_environment!'
    from /home/vijay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Here is my application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
# require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"


if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module MongoSt
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'

  end
end
```

Gemfile :

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'



# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'jquery-rails'

#mongo db drivers
gem "mongo_mapper"
gem "bson_ext"
gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
end
```

I am new to this environment , so kindly help me in this or provide me any links which will be helpful. 
Thanks

Comment: Could you paste what you put in your application.rb and gemfile ?

Comment: I have included application.rb and gemfile on post kindly have a look at this

Comment: bundle install worked no problem ?

Comment: ya bundle install works properly

Comment: Do you have a `config/mongodb.yml`? If yes, can we see it?

Comment: Hey thanks finally its working , i did mistake i have created file called 'config/mongo.yml' now i have changed it into 'config/mongodb.yml'

Comment: FYI: the give away was `psych.rb` in the stack trace right after `mongo_mapper/railtie.rb`, Psych is one of the YAML parsing engines for Ruby (the other is Syck).

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer for it, Firstly i have created file called '**mongo.yml**' in config folder , i have renamed file to '**mongodb.yml**'. Its working fine. Basically this file contains details about the connection of database. 
 mongodb.yml file contain the following code

```
base: &base
adapter: mongodb
database: test
host: localhost

development:
<<: *base
```